# How can I store questions from this array in my database having a category as parent

Tags: php, sql, arrays, database

I have a dynamic list in which people can add categories and for each category they can add questions.

At the moment I store the title of the entire list in my database and the categories, both work but I can't figure out how to store the questions. I have them in an array so it shouldn't be that hard, still I can't get it to work.

This is my database structure:

```
templates:
id - template id
title - name of list (template)
id_company (company list belongs to, irrelevant for this question)

questioncat:
id - id of category
title - name of category
tid - template id that the category belongs to

questions:
id - question id
question - the actual question
catid - category id that the questions belong to
```

With the code I have at the moment I can add a template with categories linked to it. I do this with the code below:

```
$conn = new Connection;

$arr = $_POST['lijst'];

$companyid = $_POST['companyid'];

$store = [];

// pull off first arr element
$title = array_shift($arr);
// save title to store
$store['title'] = $title['name'];

// Insert template title and companyid
$inserttemplate = '
INSERT INTO templates (title, id_company) VALUES ("'.$conn->real_escape_string($title["value"]).'","'.$conn->real_escape_string($companyid).'")';
$inserttemplatecon = $conn->query($inserttemplate);
$lastinserted = $conn->inserted_id();

$currCat = '';
foreach($arr as $a) {
  $val = $a['value'];
  // handle category
  if($a['name'] == 'category[]') {
    // save cat name
    $currCat = $val;

        $insertcats = '
        INSERT INTO questioncat (title, tid) VALUES ("'.$conn->real_escape_string($currCat).'", "'.$conn->real_escape_string($lastinserted).'")';
        $insertcatscon = $conn->query($insertcats);

    // init questions array
    $store[$currCat] = [];

        echo $store[$currCat];
  }else {
    // add question to question array
    $store[$currCat][] = $val;
  }
}
```

If I print the array `$store` when adding some example categories/questions this is an example result:

```
Array
(
    [title] => lijsttitle
    [Category 1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Question 1
            [1] => Question 2
            [2] => Question 3
        )

    [Category 2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Question 1
        )

    [Category 3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Question 1
        )

    [Category 4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Question 1
            [1] => Question 2
        )

)
```

I tried echoing `echo $store[$currCat];` to see if I can show the questions but this is an array so it just shows Array, if I print it I just see `Array()`.

How can I add the questions to my database with for each question the correct category id it belongs to?

`var_dump` of `$arr` as requested below:

```
array(11) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "category[]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "Category 1"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "question[]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "Question 1"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "question[]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "Question 2"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "question[]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "Question 3"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "category[]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "Category 2"
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "question[]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "Question 1"
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "category[]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "Category 3"
  }
  [7]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "question[]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "Question 1"
  }
  [8]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "category[]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "Category 4"
  }
  [9]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "question[]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "Question 1"
  }
  [10]=>
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(10) "question[]"
    ["value"]=>
    string(10) "Question 2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Please either explain the structure of arr or do a var_dump($arr) and show the results.

Comment: @Penguine I added the dump to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help:

```
foreach($arr as $ar){

foreach($ar as $key=>$val){
        if(($key=="name")&&($val=="category[]"))
            //insert into category table here and retrieve its id(category Id)
        elseif(($key=="name")&&($val=="question[]"))
            //insert into questions table with the retrieved category Id.
       }
}
```

Comment: If I add this code, everything is stored correctly except all values are either `category[]` or `question[]`. I insert `$val` in my database.